# Are there noncongruence subgroups (of finite index) of the modular group generated only by 2 or 3 elements?

Tags: modular-group, gr.group-theory

By the modular group I mean either $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ or $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

Where can I find examples of these?

Another question: is there a good (ideally analytical, but possibly computer-aided) way to determine if a subgroup of the modular group generated by some given matrices has finite index, and possibly allowing to compute the index?

Comment: For your 2nd question, Stallings gives an algorithm which determines whether a set of elements of a finite rank free group generates a finite index subgroup, and computes the index of that subgroup. His algorithm adapts easily, I believe, to finite free products of cyclic groups. In the case of $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}) \approx \mathbb{Z}/2 * \mathbb{Z}/3 = \langle a \rangle * \langle b \rangle$, you would first convert your input matrices into words in $a,b$, and then carry out the Stallings algorithm.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer to your Question 1. is that there are not rank 2 subgroups of $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, but there are rank 3 subgroups. This follows from a [result of Wohlfahrt](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256059574). He shows in Theorem 5
that any non-congruence subgroup $\Gamma < PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ has index $\geq 7$. 
Misha points out in a comment to his answer that a finite coarea fuchsian group of rank $N$ has $Area(\mathbb{H}^2/\Gamma)\leq 2\pi(N-1)$. Therefore in the case $\Gamma$ is non-congruence, $Area(\mathbb{H}^2/\Gamma)=[PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}):\Gamma] Area(\mathbb{H}^2/PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})) \geq 7\pi/3$. Thus, $N=rank(\Gamma) \geq 3$. Misha's claim (in the non-uniform case) follows from an application of the free product decomposition of non-uniform Fuchsian group into cyclic groups, [Grushko's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grushko_theorem), and Gauss-Bonnet.

Wohlfahrt also gives an example of a non-congruence subgroup of index $7$ in $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. On p. 531, he points out that there exists an index $7$
subgroup with two cusps. One determines that the group has genus $0$,
and two cone points of orders $2$ and $3$ respectively. This group is therefore
rank $3$, isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\ast \mathbb{Z}/2\ast\mathbb{Z}/3$. I 
didn't check, but I think this also lifts to a rank 3 subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Can't you just lift the three generators arbitrarily, and produce a noncongruence subgroup of rank 3 of index either 7 or 14?

Comment: Yes, good point. I had in mind showing the preimage is rank 3, but it doesn't matter. 

Answer (score 8):

1. For your first question: "Most" 2-generated subgroups of the modular group will have infinite covolume, so they are not congruence subgroups. For instance, take the subgroup generated the upper and lower triangular matrices with off-diagonal entries equal to $2$.
2. For your second question: There is Jorgensen's algorithm for constructing fundamental domain for a subgroup of $PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$ with the given set of generators, see my answer in [(un)decidability in matrix groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47961/undecidability-in-matrix-groups/90840#90840)
   After you construct such fundamental polygon you can check if it has any edges contained in the circle at infinity of $\mathbb H^2$. This is equivalent to having infinite index. Analytically, finite index is equivalent to finiteness of covolume.

Comment: Perhaps oxeimon is interested in noncongruence subgroups *of finite index*, which would make this a harder problem (but probably still feasible).

Comment: Noam: Perhaps. Then the question becomes more interesting and I do not know examples, but: On general grounds, if $\Gamma$ is an $N$-generated Fuchsian group of finite covolume then $Area(H^2/\Gamma)\le 2\pi(N-1)$, which gives an upper bound on index of $\Gamma$ in $PSL(2,Z)$.  Tim Hsu in "Identifying congruence subgroups of the modular group", Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 124, 1351-1359, gives an algorithm to determine if given $\Gamma$ is a congruence subgroup or not. Putting two things together, somebody can then search for non-congruence subgroups of rank $\le 3$. 

Comment: Using graphs of groups, it is easy to enumerate the finitely many conjugacy classes of subgroups of rank $\le 3$. Each one corresponds to a finite connected bi-partite graph; each vertex in the first set is either of valence 2 or of valence 1 labelled with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$; and each vertex in the second is either of valence 3 or of valence 1 labelled with $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. Congruence subgroups being normal, each such graph whose self-isomorphism group is NOT transitive on edges is not a congruence subgroup, and the vast majority satisfy that.

Comment: @Lee: principal congruence subgroups are normal, but not a general congruence subgroup, which need only contain a principal one as a subgroup. 

Comment: Oops, OK. But anyway, that's the quickest way to enumerate the relevant finite index subgroups. On top of which, the number of generators is easy to compute: it's the sum of the rank of the underlying graph plus the number of points labelled with a nontrivial group.

Comment: By Theorem 5 of this paper, the smallest index of a non-congruence subgroup is 7 (an example is given right before the theorem). By Misha's estimate, there are no rank 2 non-congruence subgroups. One could then check Wohlfahrt's example to see if it is rank 3. 

http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.ijm/1256059574

Comment: Using the graphical method described in my earlier comments, I enumerated conjugacy classes of finite index subgroups of $PSL(2,Z) = \mathbb{Z}/2 * \mathbb{Z}/3$ having rank $\le 3$ and index $\ge 7$. There are fifteen of them, here is a summary. Each of the six classes of rank 2 subgroups has index $\le 6$. Of rank 3 classes there are twenty one altogether, fifteen of which have index $\ge 7$: two of index $7$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/2*\mathbb{Z}/3$; two of index $8$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}/3 * \mathbb{Z}/3$; ....

Comment: three of index $9$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}/2$; three of index $10$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}/3$; and five of index $12$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$. The only one of this list which is itself normal is the index $12$ group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ (arising from the barycentric subdivision of the 1-skeleton of the tetrahedron) whose quotient is the alternating group of order 12. 

Comment: Wohlfart's example has index 7 and two cusps. He gives a formula for index which amounts to $index = 6 \cdot (\mathbb{Z}-rank) + 4 e_3 + 3 e_2 - 6$ where the $\mathbb{Z}$-rank is the number of $\mathbb{Z}$-free factors and equals $2 \cdot (genus) + (number of cusps) - 1$, $e_3$ is the number of $\mathbb{Z}/3$ free factors, and $e_2$ is the number of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ free factors. From this I believe it follows that Wohlfart's example is in one of the two $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}/3 * \mathbb{Z}/2$ conjugacy classes mentioned above.

Comment: Wohlfart also mentions that in his example, one cusp has amplitude 1 and the other has amplitude 6. If you trace a closed curve in the graph of groups corresponding to the cusp, the amplitude equals half the edge length. Exactly one of the two $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}/3 * \mathbb{Z}/2$ examples exhibits this possibility. I'll describe the graph. 

Comment: Draw a circle of two edges. To one of its vertices, attach one endpoint of an arc of two edges. From the opposite endpoint of that arc, attach an arc of one edge with opposite vertex labelled $\mathbb{Z}/2$, and attach another arc of two edge with opposite vertex labelled $\mathbb{Z}/3$.

Comment: Nice Lee. It's not hard to check that an orbifold with 2 cusps and cone points of orders 2 and 3, and euler characteristic $-7/6$ must have fundamental group $Z\ast Z/2\ast Z/3$, which is what I referred to in my answer. 

Answer (score 6):

A. J. Scholl has written a series of articles on modular forms on noncongruence subgroups. In the article

[On the Hecke algebra of a noncongruence subgroup](http://ams.u-strasbg.fr/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=scholl&s5=noncongruence&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=2&mx-pid=1446557), Bull. London Math. Soc. 29 (1997), no. 4, 395–399

he gives two examples of index 7 subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ generated by 3 elements :

$$\Gamma_{4,3} = \Bigl\langle \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 2 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \Bigr\rangle$$

$$\Gamma_{5,2} = \Bigl\langle \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 5 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \Bigr\rangle$$

The subscripts refer to the widths of the cusps (both groups have exactly two cusps).

Comment: Assuming your "width" means Wohlfart's "amplitude" in my answer, neither one of these is Wohlfart's example, which would be $\Gamma_{6,1}$ in your notation. I checked and can verify that these are the other two index 7 examples isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}/3 * \mathbb{Z}/2$ that I allude to in my answer.

Comment: I checked in Wohlfahrt and yes, amplitude is the same as width.

Answer (score 6):

I've compiled my serial comments on Misha's answer with this new answer, not containing any information unavailable in the other answers, but working out Wohlfart's example mentioned by Agol in more explicit detail. In particular there is more than one distinct conjugacy class (up to orientation reversal) of index 7 subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}/3 * \mathbb{Z}/2$ and with two cusps; I have found three such. Extra information Wohlfart gives regarding amplitude of the cusps pins down which one it is.

The modular orbifold, of genus zero with one cusp, one $\mathbb{Z}/3$ cone point, and one $\mathbb{Z}/2$ cone point, deformation retracts to a graph of groups $G$ consisting of the unique geodesic connecting those two cone points. Covering spaces of the modular orbifold up to covering isomorphism (in the category of orbifolds), correspond to coverings of $G$ up to covering isomorphism (in the category of graphs of groups), the covering graph sitting as a deformation retraction of the covering orbifold. Each finite degree covering graph of $G$ is a finite, connected, bipartite graph of groups, where each vertex in one set is either of valence 2 labelled with the trivial group or of valence 1 labelled with $\mathbb{Z}/2$, and each vertex in the other set is either of valence 3 labelled with the trivial group or of valence 1 labelled with $\mathbb{Z}/3$; all edges are labelled with the trivial group. Its fundamental group is a free product of: $e_\infty$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, $e_3$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}/3$, and $e_2$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2$. The minimal number of generators equals $e_\infty + e_3 + e_2$, and $e_\infty = 2 \cdot $(genus)$ + $(number of cusps)$ - 1$. Also, Wolhfart gives a formula for index taken from a paper of Peterrson (which Agol alludes to in his answer), and which amounts to
$$index = 6 \cdot e_\infty + 4 e_3 + 3 e_2 - 6
$$

Wolhfart's noncongruence example has index 7 with two cusps, one of amplitude 1 and one of amplitude 6. The amplitude is equal to half the number of edges of the edge path in the graph that is obtained from a circle around the cusp by projecting that circle to the graph under the deformation retraction. If one adds the restriction that this is the 3 generator example, one gets $e_\infty = e_2 = e_3 = 1$, and the corresponding hyperbolic orbifold is a twice punctured disc (an open annulus) with one $\mathbb{Z}/2$ cone point and one $\mathbb{Z}/3$ one point. If one requires the cusp at the origin to have amplitude 1 and the cusp at infinity to have amplitude 6, this is enough to pin down the graph in $\mathbb{C}-0$ uniquely (up to isotopy and orientation reversal).

First draw a circle around the origin, subdivided at two vertices into two edges. One of those vertices will have valence 2 in the graph, the other will have valence 3. Attach to the latter vertex an arc of two edges on the outside of the circle; the interior vertex of that arc will have valence 2, and its opposite vertex will have valence 3. Attach to that opposite vertex two arcs: one arc has one edge and opposite vertex of valence 1 labelled $\mathbb{Z}/2$; the other has two edges, interior vertex of valence 2, and opposite vertex of valence 2 labelled $\mathbb{Z}/3$.

Answer (score 4):

$\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}\DeclareMathOperator\F{\mathbf{F}}$Let me provide a purely group-theoretic answer.

Let $H$ be a subgroup of finite index in $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{Z})\simeq C_2\ast C_3$. Then, by Kurosh, $H$ is isomorphic to $C_2^{\ast e_2}\ast C_3^{\ast e_3}\ast \mathbf{Z}^{\ast e_0}$ for some integers $e_0,e_2,e_3\ge 0$ (clearly finite, and satisfying $e_2+e_3+e_0\ge 2$).

Since these are virtually free and since in a free group the index determines the rank, the triple $(e_2,e_3,e_0)$ determines the index $f(e_2,e_3,e_0)$ of $H$ in $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$. Let me explicitly compute $f$.

For any groups $A,B$, we have $A\ast B\simeq A\ltimes B^{\ast A}$ (a kind of non-commutative wreath product). Hence, if $A'$ has index 2 in $A$, then $A\ast B$ has a subgroup of index 2 isomorphic to $A'\ltimes B^\ast {A'\sqcup A'}\simeq A'\ltimes (B\ast B)^{A'}\simeq A'\ast B\ast B$.

Given that $C_2^{e_2}$ has a subgroup of index 2 isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}^{\ast e_2-1}$ for $e_2\ge 1$ (the kernel of the map onto $C_2$ that's identity on each factor), we deduce that $2f(e_2,e_3,e_0)=f(0,2e_3,2e_0+e_2-1)$ for $e_2\ge 1$.

Similarly, given that $C_3^{e_3}$, for $e_3\ge 1$ has a subgroup of index 3 isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}^{\ast 2(e_3-1)}$, we deduce similarly that $3f(e_2,e_3,e_0)=f(3e_2,0,3e_0+2(e_3-1))$ whenever $e_3\ge 1$.

Hence $$f(e_2,e_3,e_0)=f(0,2e_3,2e_0+e_2-1)/2=f(0,0,6e_0+3(e_2-1)+2(2e_3-1))/6$$ $$=\frac16f(0,0,6e_0+3e_2+4e_3-5)$$
whenever $e_2,e_3\ge 1$; when one or both equals zero this is still valid, by direct verification and using that $f(0,0,1+k)=f(0,0,1+sk)/s$ by the values of ranks of subgroups of finite index in free groups.

Next, $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ has index 1 in itself, so $f(1,1,0)=1$. We just checked that $f(1,1,0)=f(0,0,2)/6$ by constructing a copy of index 6 of $F_2$. So $f(0,0,2)=6$, and, in turn, $f(0,0,n)=f(0,0,1+(n-1))=(n-1)f(0,0,2)=6(n-1)$. To conclude,
$$f(e_2,e_3,e_0)=\frac16f(0,0,6e_0+3e_2+4e_3-5)= 3e_2+4e_3+6(e_0-1).$$

When the generating rank is two, i.e., $e_0+e_2+e_3=2$ (excluding $e_2=2$ as $C_2^{\ast 2}$ can't occur), we get:
$$f(1,1,0)=1,\;f(1,0,1)=3;\;f(0,1,1)=4;f(0,2,0)=2;f(0,0,2)=6.$$

Hence subgroups of finite index of generating rank 2 in $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ are precisely those subgroups of index $1,2,3,4,6$. In index 1,2 there is a single such subgroup.

---

(Sequel: this was unfinished)

So it remains to describe subgroups of index 1,2,3,4,6 in $\PSL_2(\mathbf{Z})$.

Index 1 ($\simeq C_2\ast C_3$): the whole group (= principal congruence modulo 1).

Index 2 ($\simeq C_3\ast C_3$): there is a single one. It is congruence modulo 2, since $\PSL_2(\F_2)$ is a dihedral group of order 6.

Index 3 ($\simeq C_2\ast\mathbf{Z}$ or $\simeq C_2^{\ast 3}$): up to conjugacy there are two such subgroups. One is normal, actually $\simeq C_2^{\ast 3}$: it is congruence modulo 3, since $\PSL_2(\F_3)\simeq\mathrm{Alt}_4$ has a normal subgroup of index 3. The other ones are non-normal and congruence modulo 2, since $\PSL_2(\F_2)$ has a non-normal subgroup of index 3. [One representative consists of those matrices that are $\pm I_2$ modulo 3. If I'm correct it has a single conjugacy class of elements of order 2, so this group is isomorphic to $C_2\ast\mathbf{Z}$.]

Index 4 ($\simeq C_3\ast\mathbf{Z}$ or $\simeq C_2^{\ast 2}\ast C_3$): up to conjugacy there are two such subgroups, if I'm correct. One is congruence modulo 3, since $\PSL_2(\F_3)\simeq\mathrm{Alt}_4$ has a subgroup of index 4 (of order 3). [This one has no element of order 2, hence is isomorphic to $C_3\ast\mathbf{Z}$.] One is congruence modulo $4$, since $\PSL_2(\mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z})$, which has order 48, has a subgroup of index 4 (of order 12), if I checked correctly.

Index 6 ($\simeq\mathbf{Z}^{\ast 2}$ or $\simeq C_3^{\ast 3}$ or $\simeq C_2^{\ast 4}$) is the most interesting case. I'll develop this later as it requires a number of verifications.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I wanted to add a sort of elementary answer, which shows in particular that any subgroup of $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ of index 7 isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ cannot be a congruence subgroup.  These subgroups were mentioned above, and are also fairly easy to construct by drawing a graph with two colors representing a covering space of $B\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (see [here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/11/29/drawing-subgroups-of-the-modular-group/) for a sketch of the method).  We will use theorem 2 from the [Wohlfahrt](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256059574) paper linked in Ian’s answer (which takes around one page to prove), together with the genus formula $g=1+\frac{d}{12}-\frac{\varepsilon_2}{4}-\frac{\varepsilon_3}{3}-\frac{\varepsilon_{\infty}}{2}$ where $\varepsilon_i$ is the number of elliptic points on $X(\Gamma)$ of order $i=2,3$, and $\varepsilon_{\infty}$ is the number of cusps.

Let $\Gamma$ be a subgroup of $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ of the proscribed form.  Note that subgroups of $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ correspond to covering spaces of $B\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\simeq (B\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\vee (B\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ (which is homotopy equivalent to $Y(1)$, at  least as orbifolds, as in Lee’s answer).  You can picture these covering spaces as [here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/11/29/drawing-subgroups-of-the-modular-group/).

The covering space corresponding to $\Gamma$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y(\Gamma)$ (as orbifolds), and by looking at the fibers over $B\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $B\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, respectively, we find that $Y(\Gamma)$ has one elliptic point of order 2 and one of order 3.  You can actually avoid orbifolds altogether if you’d prefer (which simply allow you to say the following more succinctly), just by noting that elliptic points of order 2 (resp. 3) correspond to conjugacy classes of order 2 (resp. 3) subgroups, which in an amalgamated product as in our case, is just the number of times $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (resp. $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$) appears in the amalgamated product.  We plug these numbers into our genus formula, $g=1+\frac{7}{12}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{\varepsilon_{\infty}}{2}=1-\frac{\varepsilon_{\infty}}{2}$.  Since the genus is an integer, there must be an even number of cusps.

Now we apply theorem 2 of the linked paper, and look at the number of cusps.  If there are two (the case of 4 or 6 are even easier), they must have indices $(1,6)$, $(2,5)$, or $(3,4)$, and in any case, 7 does not divide the order of $\operatorname{SL}_2(N)$ for $N=6,10$ or $12$, so that $\Gamma(N)$ has index not divisible by 7, and thus cannot be contained in $\Gamma$, a contradiction.

As a side note: using Euler characteristic of groups, one can show that any congruence subgroup of index 7 is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}^{*3} *\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, which shows there are 3 order 2 elliptic points and 1 order 3 elliptic point.  For a similar reason to above, using theorem 2 of Wohlfahrt, there must be only one cusp, of index 7, and the genus of $X(\Gamma)$ must be zero.

I think this is a particularly simple construction and proof of a non-congruence subgroup, using only elementary covering space theory and knowledge about the genus of a modular surface.  The question was already thoroughly answered in this thread before, but I find this way a bit easier than the answers already presented, and I’m hoping that somebody else benefits from seeing it.

Comment: I will add that I don’t know what moduli spaces the index 7 subgroups mentioned in this thread correspond to.  If anyone knows, I’d love to hear.

Comment: According to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.01336.pdf), there are, up to conjugation, 4 noncongruence subgroups of index 7. The ones with cusp widths (3,4) and (2,5) respectively classify elliptic curves with $PSL(3,2)$ and $PSL(3,4)$ covers (only ramified above the origin), in the sense that the associated modular curves are *components* of the corresponding Hurwitz stacks of $G$-covers. I have not yet found a moduli interpretation for the others.